# Increasing accuracy in integration using quad

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(x):
    return 1/math.log(x)

for i in range(1,13):
    n = 10**i
    I = quad(integrand, 1.45137, n)
    print('Li(',n,') = ' ,I[0], '   Error bound = ', I[1], sep = "")
```

In evaluating the `logarithmic integral function` the code above returns values with sufficient accuracy for `n` up to 1,000,000, then accuracy deteriorates. For my requirement I would wish to keep the error bound well below `1` even for much larger arguments, say up to `10**12`. I experimented with the `epsabs` and `limit` parameters, without any visible effect for any `n`, and since this is not a situation where the function values fall below the floating point lower limit I did not think it worthwhile trying my luck with multi-precision shenanigans. Any tips anyone?

Comment: Actually, I just realize my assumption that multiple precision float is not relevant is wrong. For large values of `n` values `1/log(x)` will of course fall below any bound no matter how small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the error tolerance:

```
I = quad(integrand, 1.45137, n,epsrel = 1e-012)
```

output:

```
Li(10) = 6.165597450825269   Error bound = 1.3760057428455556e-12
Li(100) = 30.126139530117598   Error bound = 3.845093652017017e-10
Li(1000) = 177.60965593619017   Error bound = 1.0048009489777205e-08
Li(10000) = 1246.1372138454267   Error bound = 2.5251966557222983e-11
Li(100000) = 9629.808998996832   Error bound = 4.4348515334357425e-10
Li(1000000) = 78627.54915740821   Error bound = 8.356797391525394e-09
Li(100000000) = 5762209.375445976   Error bound = 1.7291372054824457e-06
Li(1000000000) = 50849234.956999734   Error bound = 1.7689864637237228e-05
Li(10000000000) = 455055614.58662117   Error bound = 0.00014576268969193965
Li(100000000000) = 4118066400.621609   Error bound = 0.0009848731833003443
Li(1000000000000) = 37607950280.804855   Error bound = 0.01345062255859375
```

Comment: `epsrel` certainly does the job for a little while, but soon `1/log(x)` falls below the floating point accuracy and I am warned that returned tolerances `may be underestimated`. So, I will have to read up on `multiprecision floats`.

Comment: Further on the topic of `float precision`, is there such a thing available as `unlimited precision`?. I suspect that's what I will end up needing.

Comment: 1/log(x) will be correct for very large numbers due to the nature of log(x)

Comment: How large are your numbers?

Comment: Setting `epsrel = 1e-012` takes me to `x = 1e-012`. Increasing `epsrel` seems to reach the limit of `float precision`. I would have liked to go to `x = 10**18`. Browsing through past questions it seems there have been various attempts at establishing unlimited ` float` precision. Considering that python supports unlimited `integer arithmetic`, why not unlimited floats or decimals?

Comment: I am currently reading in the Python 3.9.1 documentation on `decimals`. This may well turn out to be the answer to what I need. Shall see, looks promising.

Comment: `mpmath` may be the way to go! Is it current? May have to post a question or two before I get the syntax right.

Comment: Problem with unlimited float precision is that even simple calculations like 1/3 produce results that are infinitely long when expressed as a decimal.

Comment: I ditched 'decimal' once I had become aware of `mpmath`, which proves to be very useful indeed. I understand `mpmath` is used in `Sage` -these guys are into number theory and know how to handle BIG numbers. `mpmath` allows to set unlimited precision, and although I have so far been unable to get their faster `gmpy integer` version working, working with the much slower standard `Python integers` I tested my logarithmic integral function, with accuracy set to 50 digits, up to `1e+24` , and results are presented in under a second. Astonishing!  I have taken your advise on board.